# How to write a Regular expression for the serialize json data in jemter

Tags: javascript, jmeter

Can anyone help writing regular expression for the below: I need to extract the UserId from the below and pass it to other post data.

```
{
 "Mentors": [],
 "Participants": [],
 "UserAndRoles": [
  {
   "UserAndRoleId": "7d5fc1b9-b11b-4971-a49a-6e553e442e31",
   "UserId": 6501,
   "RoleId": 11,
   "CFDYear": "2017-18"
  }
 ],
  "UserId": 6501,
  "MobileNo": null,
  "Gender": null,
  "CreatedOn": "2017-09-05T16:53:05.47",
  "UpdatedOn": "2018-08-09T04:11:57.217",
  "IsActive": true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to extract value from JSON, You have `UserId` in level 2, so use two dots as regular expression below:

```
$..UserId
```

Or get UserId in level 1:

```
$.UserId
```

Choose Match No. `1` to get the first value.

Comment: I tried both the ways but not getting the UserId extracted

Comment: @coder I have edit your question so maybe I missing something, can you show the exact response shown in View Results Tree?

Comment: "{\r\n  \"Mentors\": [],\r\n  \"Participants\": [],\r\n  \"UserAndRoles\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"UserAndRoleId\": \"7698d2a3-893a-4bb1-b2e8-c9b6dc89668d\",\r\n      \"UserId\": 6511,\r\n      \"RoleId\": 11,\r\n      \"CFDYear\": \"2017-18\"\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"UserId\": 6511,\r\n  \"FullName\": \"mohit gupta\",\r\n  \"MobileNo\": null,\r\n  \"Gender\": null,\r\n  \"CreatedOn\": \"2017-09-20T06:17:29.26\",\r\n  \"UpdatedOn\": \"2018-07-27T10:40:54.537\",\r\n  \"IsActive\": true,\r\n }"

Comment: Above is the response body in the view result tree.

Comment: if this is really the output, you need regular expression extractor with the following expression `"UserId\\": (\d+)`

Comment: I have another Question that is :

I am getting response data as "7698d2a3-893a-4bb1-b2e8-c9b6dc89668d" this. Now I want to use this response data in another request.
So how to store it in a variable and pass it to another request. ??

Comment: @just put variable name as `var` and use it later as `${var}`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use "UserId" without any dots